# In NASM labels next to each other in memory are printing both strings instead of first one

Tags: assembly, x86, label, nasm

I am having an issue while programming in NASM. I am learning how to develop an OS purely in assembly and have started by creating a boot loader.

My goal currently is to print "Hello, World!" and "Goodbye!" using the the BIOS interrupt 0x10.

The issue I seem to be having occurs while printing values on the screen. Two labels appear to be next to each other in memory causing printing one string to print the contents of the other string.

Why isn't `hlen` stopping the loop at the end of the first string?

```
    [org 0x7c00]

    mov ah, 0x0e

    mov bx, HELLO_MSG
    mov cx, hlen                                                                                                                                              
    call print_string

    mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
    mov cx, glen                                                                                                                                              
    call print_string

    jmp $

    %include "print_string.asm"


    HELLO_MSG db 'Hello, World!',0
    GOODBYE_MSG db 'Goodbye!',0


    hlen equ $ - HELLO_MSG
    glen equ $ - GOODBYE_MSG

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

BUGS:

1. Prints goodbye message twice

   **This is due to the HELLO_MSG printing `Hello, World!` and `Goodbye!`**.
   I believe this occurs because the `Hello_MSG` label is right next to the `GOODBYE_MSG` label in memory

```
;;;print_string.asm
print_string:                   ;cx = string length                                                                                                                                                          
                                ;bX = string label - memory offset                                                                                                                       
                                ; -- if you want the data at a memory adress use [bx]                                                                                                                        
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10

        inc bx

        loop print_string

        ret
```

Comment: See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more details.

Comment: [Hello World printing both messages with one system call? Why does length equ $-msg1 include both?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72690806) is a duplicate with a shorter question, using 32-bit Linux system calls.  ([How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) is still the canonical Q&A for this in general.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your computation of `hlen` includes the string `Goodbye!` because it comes after the defintion of `GOODBYE_MSG`. The expression `$ - HELLO_MSG` is the number of bytes between the label `HELLO_MSG` and the line where `hlen` is defined. That is why your first call to `print_string` prints both messages.

Try this order instead:

```
HELLO_MSG db 'Hello, World!',0
hlen equ $ - HELLO_MSG

GOODBYE_MSG db 'Goodbye!',0
glen equ $ - GOODBYE_MSG
```

See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more details, including this as an example.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked, and I understand the concept. I am leaving a link here to an explain how the $ and $$ commands works.http://www.csc.depauw.edu/~bhoward/asmtut/asmtut9.html

Comment: @HoodedMan: You should drop the zeros from your messages, as they should not be displayed and aren't used as terminators here. (They will probably be output as funky spaces.)