# why do all the declared variable print when only one was asked for in asm

Tags: assembly, nasm

So in the code below, I am attempting to print just the good bye message but all 3 get printed and if a 4 variable is added, it get printed as well .
What could be causing this and how can I fix it.

I have read some posts which suggest something about a null terminator however using

```
goodbyeMsg db " powering off",0

goodbyeMsg db " powering off$",10, 13, 0

goodbyeMsg db " powering off",10, 13, 0
goodbyeMsg db " powering off$"
```

did not work

the sample code:

```
section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,goodbyeMsg
        mov edx,lenGoodbyeMsg
        int 80h

        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx ,0
        int 80h

section .data
    welcomeMsg db "Welcome, to Ugo Air Condition"
    lenWelcomeMsg db $-lenWelcomeMsg
    goodbyeMsg db " powering off"
    lenGoodbyeMsg  db $-lenGoodbyeMsg
    help db "enter q w e r t y u "
    lenHelp   db  $-lenHelp
    quitKey db "q"
    lenQuitKey equ $ - quitKey
    defaultMode db "Stationary"
    lenDefaultMode equ $-defaultMode

    defaultTemp db 18
    defaultFanSpeed db 2


section .bss
    userInput resb 10
    powerState resb 10
    currentTemp resb 10
    currentMode resb 10
    currentFanSpeed resb 10
```

the output:

powering offenter q w e r t y u qStationarys

the result of strace

```
execve("./air", ["./air"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=5169 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
enter q w e r t y u qStationary) = 2048 "..., 134516943 powering off
_exit(0)                                = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Because you defined the end of all your strings in the same place? Move the length definitions to the end of the appropriate strings.

Comment: the `$` is "current" line

Comment: I.e. the way you wrote it, you would have to do `len equ msg1 - msg` `len1 equ msg2 - msg1` `len2 equ $ - msg2` ... or move the length definitions right after the particular string, then you can use special symbol `$` for each "end of string" address.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but i have edited the question since the proposed solution didn't solve the problem when applied to my actual code

Comment: Use `strace ./air > /dev/null` to avoid mixing the trace with the regular stdout.  It looks like there was probably a `write` system call that returned `2048`, but a carriage return somewhere seems to have overwritten the trace output for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the db written in the .data section. Changing them to equ fixed my problem. Thanks just for the help everyone.

Comment: I should have highlighted that in my answer.  It's in there in a section by itself; didn't realize you missed it.

Answer (score 2):

`lenGoodbyeMsg  db $-lenGoodbyeMsg` emits *one* byte in the data section, with value `0` (because you use `lenGoodbyeMsg` instead of `goodbyeMsg`).

It's followed in the data section by the ASCII codes for `e`, `n`, and `t`, from the start of the data following the `help:` label.  If you had loaded a dword from `lenGoodbyeMsg`, you would have gotten a very large number.

---

But none of that data even matters, because `mov edx,lenGoodbyeMsg` puts the *address* of the `lenGoodbyeMsg` label into edx, and that large number becomes the length arg to `sys_write`.  If you ran your program under `strace`, you'd see a very large length being passed to `sys_write`.  It's a bit surprising that sys_write doesn't just fail with `-EFAULT` without printing anything; I guess it's printing the first page before detecting the fault?

(Or else you didn't update the question after rewriting your code, which was initially a duplicate of [In NASM labels next to each other in memory are causing printing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897633/in-nasm-labels-next-to-each-other-in-memory-are-causing-printing-issues).)

---

`mov edx,lenGoodbyeMsg` would be the right instruction if you'd written
**`lenGoodbyeMsg equ $ - goodbyeMsg`** instead of `db`, like every working example of getting the assembler to calculate lengths for you.  **Because then `lenGoodbyeMsg` would be an assembler constant, not an address.**

See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more details.

---

Of course null terminators didn't work: you're using `sys_write` which takes a pointer + length and works on arbitrary binary data.

C library functions like `puts` / `printf` / `strstr` take null terminated implicit-length strings.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but after fixing those errors, I still got the same error only without the powering off  

output:
enter q w e r t y u qStationarys

Comment: @uhexos: What does `strace` say you're passing as args to `sys_write`?  Are you sure you replaced all the `db` lines with `lenGoodbyeMsg equ $ - goodbyeMsg` or the equivalent for other messages?

Comment: honestly I just started assembly like a week ago and have no background in c, so could you please explain what you mean by strace, Yes I have replaced all db line appropriately and can update my question with a newer version if it would help

Comment: @uhexos: Run `strace ./my_program` to print a trace of all the system calls it makes.  Google would have told you that.  And sure, add a new section to your question with your new version if you want.

Comment: @uhexos: put the strace log in your question, where you can use code formatting.  Because you left out the actual `write()` call.  Or try using `strace ./air > /dev/null` so *only* the trace shows in your terminal, not the regular output.  Or use `strace -o foo.trace ./air` to log to a file instead of the terminal, so the trace is again separated from the regular stdout.  (Probably there was a carriage return somewhere in the non-ASCII garbage bytes you're printing out by passing too large a length, so the `write( ...` stuff on your terminal is overwritten).

Comment: sys_write does not care about the NUL-character, so you just could obmit it. It only matters in the sys_open-syscall, because file names are expected to have a NUL-character at the end.