# How to write only one string from data section in nasm?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Trying to write msg1 and msg2 sequentially on stdout to get something like this:

```
Hello
World
```

But instead prints this :

```
Hello
World
World
```

```
section .data     
                              
msg1    db 'Hello',10,0
msg2    db 'World',10,0

len1    equ     $- msg1                
len2    equ     $- msg2

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
   mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging

   mov edx,len1        
   mov ecx,msg1         
   call printString     
   

   mov edx, len2
   mov ecx, msg2
   call printString 
   
   mov eax,1            
   int 0x80        
 
printString:
   mov ebx,1          
   mov eax,4           
   int 0x80       
   xor eax, eax
   ret
```

Please could somebody explain me why this happens?

Comment: Do you understand what `$-msg1` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg1    db 'Hello',10,0
msg2    db 'World',10,0

len1    equ     $- msg1                
len2    equ     $- msg2
```

The `$` symbol always stands for the current address.  So `len1 equ $ - msg1` sets `len1` to the number of bytes between the start of `msg1`, and the address reached on the line where `len1` is defined - which is *after* the `World` string.  Thus `len1` is set to 14, and when you write `len1` bytes on the first write, you are writing both `Hello` and `World`.  Then you go on to write `World` again with the second write.

(You also include the null bytes, which don't show up on a terminal but will be undesirable if you redirect output to a file.  Keep in mind that `write` doesn't pay any attention to null-termination; if there is a null byte included in the count of bytes to be written, it writes it.)

So what you want instead is

```
msg1    db 'Hello',10
len1    equ     $ - msg1    
msg2    db 'World',10
len2    equ     $ - msg2
```

Now `len1` is defined immediately after the string whose length it's supposed to represent, so its value will be 6 as desired.  I also removed the 0 bytes from both strings.

Comment: We already have a canonical duplicate for this, [In NASM labels next to each other in memory are causing printing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26897633). 
 (Which has links to [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) for full details).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ah, thanks.  Interesting, it's precisely the same bug on a different OS, even including the unwanted null bytes.  I guess there is nothing new under the sun.