# Hello World printing both messages with one system call? Why does length equ $-msg1 include both?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section.text:
global _start

_start:
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, len1
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1 ; exit
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80


section.data:
msg1: db "Hello world", 10
msg2: db "Hello world!", 10
len1: equ $-msg1
len2: equ $-msg2
```

it prints out:
Hello world
Hello world!
but why `msg`2?

Answer (score 5):

`len1` is populated incorrectly, it should be:

```
section  .rodata        ; space needed between section directive and its operand
                        ; On Linux we normally put read-only data in .rodata

msg1: db "Hello world", 10
len1: equ $-msg1
msg2: db "Hello world!", 10
len2: equ $-msg2
```

So `len1` is a difference between current address (`$`) and the address of `msg1`. This way it would be a length of first message.

See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more details and examples.

---

Note that `section.data:` is just a label defining a symbol name with a dot in the middle.  It doesn't switch sections, so your code and data are in the `.text` section (with read-only + exec permission), which is the default section at the top of the file for `nasm -f elf32` outputs.

Use `section .data` if you want read+write without exec, or `section .rodata` on Linux if you want read-only *without* exec, where compilers put string literals and other constants to group them together separate from code.

Comment: We have a duplicate for that ([In NASM labels next to each other in memory are printing both strings instead of first one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26897633)) and a canonical  Q&A about `$` in general, including this problem. ([How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744)).  I expect those would be hard to find if you didn't know a specific phrase to search for / autocomplete, though.  The previous duplicate has a longer question for people to scroll past to get to the answer, so maybe this one's actually a better target for future dups.